# mp4-upload - is it possible to make screenshot via PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, video, upload

I have a upload-function for videos. Files are uploaded with jquery and later on the server processed by PHP.

There also is a page with all the videos as in small "thumbnail"-format .. it is not a real thumbnail but only the video in small size and without controls .. some of the videos stay black, because the first frame of the videos is black.

is there a possibility to capture a screenshot or something, so I can display some thumbnails other than a black screen?

Comment: Show us how you are currently getting the thumbnail

Comment: currently I have no thumbnail.. i display the video without controls.. ^^ .. so it  displays the first frame of the video

Comment: Then your 2nd paragraph has really confused me.

Comment: oh I understand.. sorry :) .. i have edited it

Comment: Ahh gotcha okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make screenshot with `ffmpeg` in command line. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:14.435 -vframes 1 out.png
```

If you want you can use `ffmpegthumbnailer`, it's more easy. `https://github.com/dirkvdb/ffmpegthumbnailer`

The question is - how to run it :) But I think you can solve it yourself.

Comment: hi.. thanks for the answer..  unfortunately there is no access to install a CL-program on a hosting-package .. so I need something I can run via PHP

Answer (score 0):

As @a.anon says ffmpeg is a good choice and there are well used PHP wrappers available to allow you integrate it into your PHP project:

- https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

These do require a path to the ffmpeg binaries, so that is something you would have to discuss with your hosting provider.